# how can i implementation 2 factor - authentication?

Tags: authentication

i have some question.
our company want 2 factor authentication.
but i don't know this.
I would like to create a two-time staff to authenticate when our team member accessing some object.
Is this possible ??

- ) If possible, what is the way to the AD authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this video. It can help you regarding two-step authentication.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9URPAC21Gc

Answer (score 0):

2-factor: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows

AD auth: via Identity Connect, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnLU0IoNwSw